# Angular file upload progress percentage

Tags: angular, file, file-upload, multipart

In my application that i am developing in Angular 4, user can upload multipart files into server. Files are large. I need to show the current progress of file upload process with it's percentage to user, how can i do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using a custom endpoint?

Comment: @Sajeetharan i have API on Node.js

Comment: Looks like what you're looking for https://angular.io/guide/http#tracking-and-showing-request-progress

Answer (score 28):

**This works in Angular 9 and 10** (note `observe: 'events'`)

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: token
      }))
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file_param_name', file, file.name);

this.httpClient.post(url, formData, {
    headers,
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events'
}).subscribe(resp => {
    if (resp.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        console.log('Upload complete');
    }
    if (resp.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * resp.loaded / resp.total);
        console.log('Progress ' + percentDone + '%');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Form where you will import the `HttpEventType`

Answer (score 8):

```
uploadDocument(file) {

    return this.httpClient.post(environment.uploadDocument, file, { reportProgress: true, observe: 'events' })
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding comments and explanation. This will help your reader to understand your code. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 3):

**Gajender.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpRequest, HttpEvent} from '@angular/common/http';
 import {Observable} from "rxjs";

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

       uploadFileData(url: string, file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        let formData = new FormData();
        let user = {
          name : 'Gajender'
        }
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append("user", JSON.stringify(user)); 

        let params = new HttpParams();

        const options = {
          params: params,
          reportProgress: true,
        };

        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData, options);
        return this.http.request(req);
      }
```

**user.component.ts**

```
constructor( private gajender: Gajender) { }
  @ViewChild('selectfile') el:ElementRef;   //in html we make variable of selectfile
  progress = { loaded : 0 , total : 0 };

uploadFile = (file) => {
    var filedata = this.el.nativeElement.files[0];
    this.gajender.uploadFileData('url',filedata)
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => { 
        console.log(data);
        if(data.type == 1 && data.loaded && data.total){
          console.log("gaju");
          this.progress.loaded = data.loaded;
          this.progress.total = data.total;
        }
        else if(data.body){
          console.log("Data Uploaded");
          console.log(data.body);
        }

       },
      error => console.log(error) 
    )
```

**user.component.html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
  <input type='file' [(ngModel)]="file" name="file" #selectfile >
  <button type="button" (click)="uploadFile(file)">Upload</button>
</form>
Progress
<progress [value]=progress.loaded  [max]=progress.total>
</progress>
```

Comment: Please use correct naming conventions of the objects you are using in the code for the example.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this with:

**npm i angular-progress-http**

After importing the module, you can now add below it to your ***app.module.ts*** or wherever you stack your app modules in your application.

*You will import this (in app.module.ts):*

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { ProgressHttpModule } from 'angular-progress-http';
```

Still in your app.module.ts

at @NgModule

```
@NgModule({

  imports: [

    HttpModule,

    ProgressHttpModule
  ]
})
```

Then in your component file (***whatever.component.ts***), where you want to use it. You can place this:

```
import { ProgressHttp } from 'angular-progress-http';
```

Then implement like this:

```
constructor(private http: ProgressHttp) {}
    onSubmit(): void {
        const _formData = new FormData();
        _formData.append('title', this.title);
        _formData.append('doc', this.doc);

        this.http.withUploadProgressListener(progress => { console.log(`Uploading ${progress.percentage}%`); })
        .withDownloadProgressListener(progress => { console.log(`Downloading ${progress.percentage}%`); })
        .post('youruploadurl', _formData)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Good, thanx, will give it a try

Comment: By the way doing `console.log('Uploading ${progress.percentage}%')` is kinda wrong i think , it will always log `0` or will it console log each progress change ?

Comment: yes, it will console log each progress change. you can easily use it in your view.

Comment: The percentage progress always return NaN if there is no connection and 100 if there is. How can this be achieved for tracking the whole progress percentage from 0, 1, 2, 50 to 100%? @tolulopeowolabi

Answer (score 2):

Simple we can use --

```
 upload(formData) {
return this.http.post<any>(api - url, formData, {
  reportProgress: true,
  observe: 'events'
}).pipe(
  map((event: HttpEvent) => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      return { status: 'progress', message: percentDone };
    }
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
      return event.body;
    }
  }),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

}

Comment: what is the return type of `upload()`

Answer (score 0):

use angular-loading-bar library, if you don't want to use angular-loading-bar library you can use progress callback 
eq-xhrrequest.upload.onprogress.