# How to add progress bar when click upload button?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-material-8

I work on angular 8 application I need to add progress bar

when click upload button so progress bar will work when click

button upload until finish upload

upload service

```
PostUpload(file)
{
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file,file.name);
 return this.http.post('http://localhost:61265/api/DeliverySys/', formData,{responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

component upload.ts

```
public uploadFile = () => {
this._dataService.PostUpload(this.selectedoptions.toString(),this.fileToUpload)

 .subscribe((response: Blob) => saveAs(response, this.fileToUpload.name + '.xlsx'));
}
```

component upload.html

```
<button (click)="uploadFile()"></button>
```

what I try as below

```
    this._dataService.PostUpload(this.selectedoptions.toString(),this.fileToUpload)
 
 .subscribe((event:any) => {
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
      console.log('Upload complete');
      this.message = 'Upload success.';
      this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
  }
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
      
         this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      console.log('Progress ' + this.progress + '%');
  }saveAs(event, this.fileToUpload.name + '.xlsx') 
}
);

<div class="col-md-4">
  <span class="upload">
    {{progress}}%
  </span>
  <span class="upload" >
    {{message}}
  </span>
</div>
```

but issue still exist nothing effect on progress percent
or when finish not give me uploaded success
can you help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034375/angular-file-upload-progress-percentage

Comment: can you help me  how to modify upload file function to make progress bar when make upload

Comment: how to modify ts and service to work as progress bar can you help me please ?

Comment: can any one help me please i can't use response.type with subscrbe

Comment: Try comparing your code with my working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-template-b1mnwj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: stackblitz not open

Comment: I updated my original post i still face issue progress and message not affect although file uploaded success so can you help me on that